# Can i use Organization schema for external site?

Tags: seo, google

Lets say i am developing a website that reviews organisations (Something like Glassdoor). On pages pertaining to the organization, could i use Organization markup to describe details about that organization? Or is that markup strictly confined to organization's own webpages?